# Rune или русские буквы в качестве ключа map

Tags: golang

Есть кусок кода. Задача в кратце - посчитать количество входов каждого встреченного символа в тексте.

```
var Data string
Data = *data

alphabet := map[string]int{}

fmt.Println(Data)

for i := range Data {
    currentChar := strings.ToUpper(string(Data[i]))
    fmt.Println("Data[", i, "]::", currentChar)
    alphabet[currentChar] = alphabet[currentChar] + 1
}

fmt.Println(alphabet)
```

При наборе английскими буквами - всё ОК. Ожидаемый результат.

```
abacaba
Data[ 0 ]:: A
Data[ 1 ]:: B
Data[ 2 ]:: A
Data[ 3 ]:: C
Data[ 4 ]:: A
Data[ 5 ]:: B
Data[ 6 ]:: A
map[A:4 B:2 C:1]
```

При вводе текста на русском

```
кошка
Data[ 0 ]:: Ð
Data[ 2 ]:: Ð
Data[ 4 ]:: Ñ
Data[ 6 ]:: Ð
Data[ 8 ]:: Ð
map[Ð:4 Ñ:1]
```

Подскажите, как пофиксить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, чтобы во всем разобраться [difference between 'range str' and 'range []rune(str)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49062100/is-there-any-difference-between-range-str-and-range-runestr-in-golang)

Если в кратце, то если вы уверены, что ваши данные **не будут** являться, например, кириллицей или другим символом, что является rune, то можете смело использовать

```
for i := range Data {
    fmt.Println(Data[i])
}
```

В противном случае, лучше использовать такой вариант

```
for i, r := range []rune(Data) {
    fmt.Println(string(r))
    // в данном случае r уже взят по индексу-i, при этом мы подстраховались от "необычных случаев"
}
```

Соответственно мой вопрос решен и вот код:

```
var Data string
Data = string(*data)

alphabet := map[string]int{}

fmt.Println(Data)

for i, r := range []rune(Data) { // add []rune for Cyrillic chars
    currentChar := strings.ToUpper(string(r))
    fmt.Println("Data[", i, "]::", currentChar)
    alphabet[currentChar] = alphabet[currentChar] + 1
}

fmt.Println(alphabet)
```

Comment: Нет никакого смысла делать `[]rune(str)`, т.к. речь идёт о выделении массива размером `количество_рун*sizeof(int32) + 3`. Дополнительно выделение памяти, никак не оправданное.

Comment: И нет смысла использовать `strigns.ToUpper(string(r))`, т.к. есть [unicode.ToUpper](https://godoc.org/unicode#ToUpper)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы перебрать строку по рунам нужно либо

```
for _, r := range  "строка" {
    // r содержит руну
}
```

Либо

```
import (
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    var s = "строка"
    for len(s) > 0 {
        r, w := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s[i:])
        // r содержит руну
        s = s[w:]
    }
}
```

Доступ оп индексу возвращает конкретный байт, а не руну. Т.к. руна может состоять из нескольких байт, например из двух для символов Киррилицы. При этом для латинского алфавита размер руны - один байт, поэтому для латинского алфавита работает и так.

Пример на [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/583U6oUnH1S), рекомендуется [тур по Go](https://go-tour-ru-ru.appspot.com/welcome/1).